# xenserver 7 xe vdi-resize this VDI is in use by some other operation

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine, xenserver

The Xenserver 7 has 5 VMs (W2K12R2). I don't expand the disk on a VM.

```
This operation cannot be performed because this VDI is in use by some
 other operation vdi: 8de90b86-4318-409a-8b33-28d066fd1484 (Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit) 0) operation: resize
```

The VM is offline, there are no tasks running, there is no snapshot, no hidden objects.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to enlarge the hard disk of the VM. I can extend all VMs, only this VM does not do it.  DVD is not loaded, VM is down, no hidden objects, no tasks.
How can I find out which operation prevents the extension and stop this operation?